# Bitbucket workflow query

Tags: git, workflow

We have a VDS and a local dev server and we are just starting to get into the whole GIT workflow. We'd like to have each developer (4) make changes on either the dev or master branches and have those changes automatically filter down to each server where appropriate. I've read up on post hooks once a push is made however I can't seem to get it working on the dev server. Our dev server is on a copy of mac server which we also use to serve files to the rest of our design team etc. Using Mamp Pro we have also pointed the IP address to allow client access for dev views outside of our local network.

We're somewhat technical literate but could use a simple approach that would give us GIT workflow on both a dev and master branches without necessarily having to FTP into the host every time we need to make a change. Currently we're editing on the live server and have no accountability on code changes/rollbacks etc

I've also tried using a service called ftploy but that doesn't appear to be working either.

I've created a new user and permitted access to the htdocs folder within mamp however when I try to perform a post hook request it doesn't pull the latest version down.